# Grails Redirect not working when accessed through remote or other server

Tags: grails, redirect

I am stuck at one point. We have to implement a feature which will redirect to login page with a message saying "Your session is expired, please login again!".

For this, I planned to redirect to a URL but redirection is not working! Following is the situation in my environment.

Grails Server:

```
http://SERVER_ONE/MyApp
```

Widgets (UI) Server:

```
http://SERVER_TWO/widgets/myWidget (different from grails server)
```

Login page:

```
http://SERVER_TWO/widgets/login
```

Config.groovy file already contains `grails.serverURL = "http://SERVER_TWO/widgets/"`

When I access the URL directly from grails server, e.g.

```
http://SERVER_ONE/MyApp
```

with invalid session, redirection works fine.

But redirection doesn't work when accessed from Widget page which is running on different server.

Redirect code is as following

`redirect(uri: "http://SERVER_TWO/widgets/login?sessionExpired=true")`

It would be great help to me, kindly respond, as I am relatively new to Grails development.

Comment: Where is the piece of code that is supposed to do a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your sessions distributed across the servers? By default sessions are not cross-server.